# Add two legend title whith ggplotly and style function (plotly)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I would like to add title to my legend. The argument "fill" and "color" have the same variable : varC (14 factors).

I'm printing my ggplot with **style()** function. Without style function that's working fine but when I add it, it doesn't.   Plotly converts automatically title legend in annotation on the top of legend ... How two add two annotations with the correct position ? Any suggestions ?

```
g.mean <- ggplot(ex,aes(x = xx,y=yy,color=varC)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=Born_Inf, ymax=Born_Sup, fill=varC), alpha=0.1) + 
  labs(title="My graph title",x="xlab name",y="ylab name",color="legend line title",fill="legend ribbon title")

g.final <- style(ggplotly(g.mean, tooltip = c("varC","x","y")),hoverinfo = "value
```

[image]

**DATA :**

```
ex <- structure(list(varC = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                      1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                      1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                      2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Factor 1 ", 
                                                                                      "Factor 2 ", "Factor 3 ", "Factor 4 ", "Factor 5 ", "Factor 6 ", 
                                                                                      "Factor 7 ", "Factor 8 ", "Factor 9 ", "Factor 10 ", "Factor 11 ", 
                                                                                      "Factor 12 ", "Factor 13 ", "Factor 14 "), class = "factor"), 
                   xx = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 
                          16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
                          8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 
                          23, 24), Born_Inf = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Born_Sup = c(17581.818, 
                                                                                                                 14155.036, 25524.2469999999, 24951.481, 34183.878, 37728.0175, 
                                                                                                                 48010.01, 44755.596, 48046.356, 60104.931, 54418.6015, 37435.019, 
                                                                                                                 64601.3079999999, 47246.4585, 61987.7755, 69326.731, 62304.4115, 
                                                                                                                 53449.3399999999, 53437.4199999999, 55794.946, 68453.62, 
                                                                                                                 47811.165, 68513.1679999999, 74041.6689999999, 28746.7845, 
                                                                                                                 36246.73, 39189.0449999999, 35805.25, 48883.4844999999, 45351.89, 
                                                                                                                 51977.1845, 54361.4, 55435.92, 48106.5175, 51940.6849999999, 
                                                                                                                 53094.3600000001, 63513.4865, 59929.0134999999, 53139.8539999999, 
                                                                                                                 58254.362, 54360.603, 59249.0440000001, 63612.2044999999, 
                                                                                                                 66954.895, 60910.28, 56237.05, 57178.5909999997, 60968.39
                                                ), yy = c(4551.10238709677, 3337.98638709677, 5493.43058064516, 
                                                          6092.89220779221, 6200.23681818182, 7618.28039473684, 7724.1440397351, 
                                                          7773.62516778524, 8370.17382550336, 9662.57210884354, 10685.8747222222, 
                                                          8006.27307692308, 9465.91507042254, 9798.04366197183, 10589.8792142857, 
                                                          11966.4210869565, 10929.867173913, 10249.8120437956, 11350.3767153285, 
                                                          11389.0071428571, 11460.8877099237, 25611.2023076923, 12201.0593076923, 
                                                          12520.087890625, 8221.18950793651, 10309.0262063492, 9699.0276031746, 
                                                          9848.93274603175, 11287.6371428571, 12661.5044178628, 12017.5153225806, 
                                                          13292.703095624, 13974.0070607553, 12037.6256105611, 13703.6894859038, 
                                                          13536.1771285476, 14665.8368855219, 15646.843125, 14033.6686495726, 
                                                          14743.2014188034, 13643.2409948542, 14126.7188773748, 15954.5895789474, 
                                                          14838.0072614841, 15773.8243493761, 16819.1530755396, 13888.5933272727, 
                                                          14795.7577614679)), .Names = c("varC", "xx", "Born_Inf", 
                                                                                         "Born_Sup", "yy"), row.names = c(NA, 48L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: you should provide a reproducible example.

Comment: I update my post with exemple

Comment: I forgot but two legends is problematic with plotly. See here https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/1668